# Login to remote site with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to using cURL and its hard to find good resources for it.
What I'm trying to do is login to a remote site, by having curl do the login form and then send back that it was successful.

The code I have doesn't seem to work and only tries to show the main page of the site.

```
    $username="mylogin@gmail.com"; 
$password="mypassword"; 
$url="http://www.myremotesite.com/index.php?page=login"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "email=".$username."&password=".$password; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

What am I doing wrong. After this is working I want to redirect to another page and get content from my site.

Comment: Your `$url` should be that of gmail login, not you own script.

Comment: That is the login page. It's where the login form is located. I'm not trying to login to Gmail with this script.

Comment: did you ensure cookie.txt is writable by your script?

Comment: How do you insure that giving the right permissions ?

Comment: @pattyd I provided and accepted an answer of **my** working solution.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I had let this go for a good while but revisited it later. Since this question is viewed regularly. This is eventually what I ended up using that worked for me.

```
define("DOC_ROOT","/path/to/html");
//username and password of account
$username = trim($values["email"]);
$password = trim($values["password"]);

//set the directory for the cookie using defined document root var
$path = DOC_ROOT."/ctemp";
//build a unique path with every request to store. the info per user with custom func. I used this function to build unique paths based on member ID, that was for my use case. It can be a regular dir.
//$path = build_unique_path($path); // this was for my use case

//login form action url
$url="https://www.example.com/login/action"; 
$postinfo = "email=".$username."&password=".$password;

$cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);

//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/page/");
//do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Update: This code was never meant to be a copy and paste. It was to show how I used it for my specific use case. You should adapt it to your code as needed. Such as directories, vars etc**

Comment: +1 yes that's right and if you want to do some other requests after logging in like getting inbox messages of a user.(after logging in), You should do it like my answer. please check it

Comment: @imsiso Yes, and in my actual code I navigate several URL's to get other data as well.

Comment: can I use this on twitter?

Comment: Thanks - I've been struggling to make something similar work all morning - the one thing I was missing? COOKIEJAR :)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function build_unique_path()

Comment: @PanamaJack can you provide your "build_unique_path()" function, for completeness?

Comment: @PanamaJack Please provide "build_unique_path()" function, or adjust the answer without.

Comment: Change
$path = build_unique_path($dir);
to 
$path = "/tmp";

Comment: @DoktorJ, I commented out that line. It was never needed. That was my use case. I made a few updates because people are thinking it can be copied and pasted as is. Adapt the needed parts to your code.

Comment: you don't urlencode the username/password, this you'll likely run into issues if either contains special characters like `&` or `=` (or a bunch of others), they should be url-encoded. use ```$postinfo = http_build_query(array("email"=>$username,"password"=>$password));``` instead of ```$postinfo = "email=".$username."&password=".$password;```  (or alternatively you could do ```$postinfo = "email=".urlencode($username)."&password=".urlencode($password);``` - but http_build_query is prettier IMO

Answer (score 23):

I had same question and I found this answer [on this website](http://blog.andyhunt.info/2011/12/21/using-php-and-curl-to-log-in-to-a-website/).

And I changed it just a little bit (the curl_close at last line)

```
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypass';
$loginUrl = 'http://www.example.com/login/';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

//Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
//not to print out the results of its query.
//Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
//from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute the request (the login)
$store = curl_exec($ch);

//the login is now done and you can continue to get the
//protected content.

//set the URL to the protected file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/protected/download.zip');

//execute the request
$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

//save the data to disk
file_put_contents('~/download.zip', $content);
```

I think this was what you were looking for.Am I right?

---

And one useful related question. About how to keep a session alive in cUrl: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13020494/2226796

Comment: How can I check am I already logged in? (to skip sending login request)

Comment: @user3383675 what do you mean? Using curl to try to login to a page and check if you had logged in and then dong some other things? (With one request?)

Comment: i mean: while(some condition) { isLoggedIn() ? doSomething() : logIn() && doSomething() } Is this nessessary to login before every iteration or can I only one time send the login request and then, next iterations without login already?

Comment: This answer worked for me with one exception: After you login with POST you forgot to change back to GET for the protected file download. On some servers (in my case) it may prevent you from geting the file. Simple `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);` before the second exec fixed it for me.

Comment: This is great, thank you, it worked like a charm for me at first run (modulo my own vars). thanks!

Comment: follow redirects may be useful: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

Answer (score 18):

View the source of the login page.  Look for the `form` HTML tag.  Within that tag is something that will look like `action=`  Use that value as `$url`, not the URL of the form itself.

Also, while you are there, verify the input boxes are named what you have them listed as.

For example, a basic login form will look similar to:

```
<form method='post' action='postlogin.php'>
    Email Address: <input type='text' name='email'>
    Password: <input type='password' name='password'>
</form>
```

Using the above form as an example, change your value of `$url` to:

```
$url="http://www.myremotesite.com/postlogin.php";
```

Verify the values you have listed in `$postdata`:

```
$postdata = "email=".$username."&password=".$password;
```

and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I solved this in ImpressPages:

```
//initial request with login data

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

//another request preserving the session

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/profile');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: //Because some sites redirect and set cookies at the second page, this may be needed:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

Answer (score 3):

Panama Jack Example not work for me - **Give Fatal error: Call to undefined function build_unique_path()**. I used this code - (more simple - my opinion) :

```
// options
$login_email = 'alabala@gmail.com';
$login_pass = 'alabala4807';
$cookie_file_path = "/tmp/cookies.txt";
$LOGINURL = "http://alabala.com/index.php?route=account/login"; 
$agent = "Nokia-Communicator-WWW-Browser/2.0 (Geos 3.0 Nokia-9000i)";

// begin script
$ch = curl_init();

// extra headers
$headers[] = "Accept: */*";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";

// basic curl options for all requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 

// set first URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL);

// execute session to get cookies and required form inputs
$content = curl_exec($ch); 

// grab the hidden inputs from the form required to login
$fields = getFormFields($content);
$fields['email'] = $login_email;
$fields['password'] = $login_pass;

// set postfields using what we extracted from the form
$POSTFIELDS = http_build_query($fields); 
// change URL to login URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL); 

// set post options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTFIELDS); 

// perform login
$result = curl_exec($ch);  

print $result; 

function getFormFields($data)
{
    if (preg_match('/()/is', $data, $matches)) {
      $inputs = getInputs($matches[1]);

      return $inputs;
    } else {
      die('didnt find login form');
     }
}

function getInputs($form)
{
    $inputs = array();
    $elements = preg_match_all("/(]+>)/is", $form, $matches);
    if ($elements > 0) {
        for($i = 0;$i            $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);
            if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                $name  = $name[1];

                $value = '';
                if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                    $value = $value[1];
                }

                $inputs[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $inputs;
}

$grab_url='http://grab.url/alabala';

//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $grab_url);
//do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($html); 
die;
```

Comment: **My answer is not a copy and paste**. It was only an example of what I used. The only part that was relevant was the **curl** code. `build_unique_path` is a custom function I created and I noted that in the example as a comment.  The answer is a guide to create your own.

Comment: Ok man, not judging you, just your example not work for me, nothing personal, I just share the example that work for me. And yes this is not my code but my work is to test and format the example

Comment: did you check this code ? it does not work and what is this for loop ? and the ; at the end of line  for($i = 0;$i            $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

Comment: @Pavel +1 for the agent!

Comment: @MindRoasterMir just delete that line, and paste this one:
for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) { $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);