# Using PHP & Curl to login to my websites form

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to login to my useraccount on a site i use to download files from so i can automatically grab the file without me having to visit the site.

**This is the form:**

```
 <form method='post' action='/news.php'>
 <div>
             Username: <input class='tbox' type='text'     name='username' size='15' value='' maxlength='20' />&nbsp;&nbsp;
             Password: <input class='tbox' type='password' name='userpass' size='15' value='' maxlength='20' />&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input type='hidden' name='autologin' value='1' />
             <input class='button' type='submit' name='userlogin' value='Login' />
 </div>
 </form>
```

**Here is the PHP ive got so far.**

```
<?php
$username="my_user"; 
$password="my_passs"; 
$url="the_url"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "username=".$username."&userpass=".$password; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Am i doing something wrong? It just displays the website at the moment but doesn't log me in. Ive never used Curl before.

Thanks

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using? I see an obvious syntax error that should throw a fatal error.

Comment: yeah that was an error, fixed it now. Still doesn't log me in though.

Comment: Is your login based only on `username` and `password` posts? Maybe you are checking if `userlogin` field is set?

Comment: You have `name='userpass'` and `$password="my_passs";` change it to `$userpass="my_passs";` should work now. @Exoon

Comment: That is all that is in the form on the website i use, I'm not sure what else they have running on their site? Is there a way to check?

Comment: @Fred-ii- not sure what you mean? username and userpass is what theyre form is called then ive stored them in $username and $password, is that not right?

Comment: The input and variable must match in names. @Exoon

Comment: the variable must match the form input name really?

Comment: yepper! that's the "law of the land" ;-) try it now as I wrote it.

Comment: No it still does not work changed it to $userpass = "my_passs"; i don't see why that would make a difference anyway its only a variable.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: there's a Symfony bundle which offers pretty uniform intuitive HTTP Request/Response objects (including file uploads) and a specialized crawler (perhaps for the testing suite) which allows you to parse the response code as HTML, traverse the DOM to find forms/buttons by using CSS selectors and filling in and submitting forms, handling the ensuing redirects etc..

Comment: Well, glad you found the answer. Tricky stuff, cheers ;-) @Exoon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should send via POST all data that the orignal form is sending. So you are missing `autologin=1&userlogin=Login` in  your `$postdata`.

```
$postdata = "username=$username&userpass=$password&autologin=1&userlogin=Login";
```

Answer (score 12):

You probably need to set COOKIESESSION and COOKIEJAR options to preserve session and do another request:

```
//initial request with login data

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

//another request preserving the session

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/profile');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: Ya we have to preserve session  and see for any other variables used during authentication, set it to successfully login into system. Thanks a lot @Mangirdas Skripka

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was pretty much copy -> paste -> use.

Answer (score 3):

```
$postdata = "username=".$username."&userpass=".$password";
```

change to:

```
$postdata = "username=".$username."&userpass=".$password;
```

And also do you have this like this?

```
$url="http://www.yourdomain.com/news.php";
```

Also add this `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`.

And also this may help:

```
$headers  = array();

$headers[] = 'application/xhtml+voice+xml;version=1.2, application/x-xhtml+voice+xml;version=1.2, text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1';
$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake when i posted, i had that already it still doesn't log me in though

Comment: Yes it is. I just removed it as i didn't want to post the site.

Comment: Also add this `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`.

Comment: Nope didn't work, It displays the headers at the top of the page, but still dosen't log me in

Comment: yes, I saw, you are missing some input fields, but I thought you are not checking them...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41422/discussion-between-exoon-and-legionar)

Answer (score 1):

The page may check to see if userlogin (the submit button) has been set before it validates the user information.

It may be worth tryin the following:

```
$postdata = "username=".$username."&userpass=".$password . "&userlogin=Login";
```

Answer (score 1):

When you request a page to a site you have previously logged into, you need to use

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $Cookie);
```

You should then check the output to determine if you're currently logged in (every site will be different, but usually if the login form is not available, or a logoff button is available, you're logged in.

If you're not logged in, then you don't include CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, you inlucde the following line:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $Cookie);
```

I created 2 different, but similar functions. `CurlPage()` and `CurlLogin().` The only difference is `CurlPage()` has the `COOKIEFILE` option, `CurlLogin()` has the `COOKIEJAR` option plus the following 2 lines:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostData);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

I then call the functions like this:

```
$Source = CurlPage($Url, $Cookie);
if (!CheckLoggedIn($Source))
{
    CurlLogin($LoginUrl, $Cookie, $PostDataArray);
    $Source = CurlPage($Url, $Cookie);
}
```

Remember, some sites require multiple pages of login. First you submit a form, then you have to enter a verification code, or click a button, or something. If that's the case, your login function will possibly have to read the source take additional actions before you're logged in and the cookie you need is created and stored in `cookie.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use a headless browser - a really scalable solution. (Tell me if it works with google account :)

What I did (useful for myself as well :)

1. Install composer https://getcomposer.org (if not installed)
   Ensure it's installed by typing in command line

   ```
        composer -V
   ```
2. Create a folder, say, TryGoutte somewhere in your web server directory
3. Create a file composer.json (just to test composer):

   ```
    {
      "require": {
          "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*"
       }
    }
   ```
4. Type "composer install". It should install monolog.
5. Type "composer require fabpot/goutte". It should install all packages for
   "goutte" https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte
   (pronounced gu:t, like boot)
6. Then, create file, say try-goutte.php in TryGoutte.

   ```
     <?php
   use Goutte\Client;
   use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

   require 'vendor/autoload.php';

   $client = new \Goutte\Client();

   // Create and use a guzzle client instance that will time out after 90 seconds
   $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array(
   'timeout' => 90,
   // To overcome Curl SSL 60 error 
   // https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/issues/214
   'verify' => false,
   ));

   $client->setClient($guzzleClient);

   $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://github.com/');
   $crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Sign in')->link());
   $form = $crawler->selectButton('Sign in')->form();
   $crawler = $client->submit($form, array('login' => 'trygoutte', 'password' => 'trygoutte1'));

   print_r($crawler->text());

   ?>
   ```

Enjoy and code further!

UPDATE: implemented here http://lycenok.com/site-login/programmatic-site-login.php to check if the solution works for you