# automatic login to a website

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have got a 3rd party website, which my customer wants to me to login into in order to download some data periodicaly.
The data is customer specific, and password protected.
I have the username/password, and I have searched for ways to do the login  automatically so that I can pull data, but so far with no success.
This is a method that I have tried:
http://crunchify.com/automatic-html-login-using-post-method-autologin-a-website-on-double-click/

When I look into the login page of the website which I am trying to login to (view source), I don't see the login form, but if I click on "inspect element" in chrome on the fields of the page it does show that there is a login form hiding in there.
Any suggestions

Edit:
Here is the website which I need to autologin to: http://portal.dorad.co.il/#/Login unfortunatlly it's not in english. The first field is the username, the second field is the password and the button is the login

Edit2:
Taking pomeh's advice, I was able to find the jQuery code that is being triggerted when the text boxes are being modified. Now I want to run this script manually using **element.DomContainer.Eval**

```
(function(n,t){function vi(n){var t=n.length,r=i.type(n);return i.isWindow(n)?!1:1===n.nodeType&&t?!0:"array"===r||"function"!==r&&(0===t||"number"==typeof t&&t>0&&t-1 in n)}function ne(n){var t=li[n]={};return i.each(n.match(s)||[],function(n,i){t[i]=!0}),t}function uu(n,r,u,f){if(i.acceptData(n)){var s,h,c=i.expando,a="string"==typeof r,l=n.nodeType,o=l?i.cache:n,e=l?n[c]:n[c]&&c;if(e&&o[e]&&(f||o[e].data)||!a||u!==t)return e||(l?n[c]=e=tt.pop()||i.guid++:e=c),o[e]||(o[e]={},l||(o[e].toJSON=i.noop)),("object"==typeof r||"function"==typeof r)&&
...
(t=n(this);r=r.not(t),t.removeData(f),r.length||clearTimeout(c)},add:function(t){function s(t,u,e){var s=n(this),o=n.data(this,f);o.w=u!==i?u:s.width(),o.h=e!==i?e:s.height(),r.apply(this,arguments)}if(!u[o]&&this[e])return!1;var r;if(n.isFunction(t))return r=t,s;r=t.handler,t.handler=s}}}(jQuery,this)
```

I am not sure how to activate it and give it the relevant data.

Comment: cookies? have you tried cookies?

Comment: what is the specific issue?

Comment: You could try using curl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049393/using-php-curl-to-login-to-my-websites-form. To provide more specific solutions, I think we'll need more information.

Comment: You can ask the Customer to enable FTP. Then its just a matter of writing a small script to auto download the data.

Comment: vsync: how would cookies help me?

Comment: charlietfl: the issue is that once my page is being submitted, I am just redirected to the login form of the third party website.

Comment: Sid: I don't know PHP. Here is the page which I need to auto login to: https://portal.dorad.co.il/#/Login unfortunatlly it's not in english. The first field is the username, the second field is the password and the button is the login

Comment: Tasos: The website is 3rd party, the customer can use it, but has no influence over the coding...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do this using a web scraping framework like:

- Goutte for PHP (https://github.com/fabpot/goutte)
- Scrapy for Python (http://scrapy.org/)
- node.io for Node.js (https://github.com/chriso/node.io)
- request for Node.js (https://github.com/mikeal/request)
- WatiN for .Net (http://watin.org/)

In any case, I think a client side solutions will bring a lot of problems to do this. Maybe you can login into it using a `form` tag which points to the page, but you won't be able to manipulate the page afterwards. Also, you may not be able to use AJAX due to CORS restriction. You could embed the target page as an iframe but you can't either manipulate the page because of differents domains used (you *can* do that under certains conditions but it's hard to achieve this imho). So a server side solutions sounds better to me.

Comment: I agree that this is not a good solutions, and I might have problems after I'm logged in. I tried to use Watin solution. I actually have two 3rd party websites which I need to login to this way. With one of them I was able to login using Watin, and with the other one I was unable, since the submit button is disabled, unless you type the details manually. Do you have any idea how to baypass the disable part? Thanks!

Comment: No I don't know what's going sorry. Here's a thing I know but it may be totally unrelated: sometimes, submit buttons are disabled unless the user type something in a form input. To achieve this, an event listener *may* be added to this input and listen to "mouseup/mousepress" event. In your case, since you fill in the form programatically, there's no mouse event, so the JS event does not get triggered and the submit button is never disabled. Maybe you can try to see in your browser what's enabling the submit, and try to simulate this behavior using WatiN. Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: I already added MouseUp and MouseDown on the text fields, it does not help. unfortunately, I can't find what's firing the JS that enables the button.

Comment: Try this: open the page in Chrome and open devtools (F12). Go to Sources panel, on the right there's a "call stack" title and next to it a checkbox "async": check it and reload the page. Go to Elements panel, and find the submit button in the HTML (use the magnifier or right click on button and "inspect element"). Right click on it in the Elements view then check this: "Break on > Attributes modifications". Now, go to the page and do the normal action that triggers the button to be enabled. If every thing is ok and you're lucky enough, devtools will trigger a breakpoint for you to debug

Comment: Thanks pomeh, It looks like I'm able to do what you suggested, but I am not sure how to proceed. When the breakpoint hit I got a long jquery script. I am not sure where does it enable the button (it has the words "submit","disable","enable" many times). I also have the stack trace, this is the last thing on the call stack: i.extend.prop (jquery?v=APNpMFfvG_2NLNgSlkjERqG13xEX-Tzj8mVRjqRTabE1:1). I am not sure what to do next...

Comment: I am thinking, maybe to use  element.DomContainer.Eval and run the huge jQuery script in there, but so far I am not successful at this. I will post the jQuery script on the original question, maybe you or someone else will be able to help

Comment: When you enter in debug mode, check out the *filenames* in the stacktrace: you may have "jquery.js" (or a similar name) multiple times, then others script name which are specific to this website. The code that says "enable this button" should be in this file and not in jQuery file. The final code you should have to run with `element.DomContainer.Eval` would be something like this: `$('#someButton').removeAttr('disabled')`. Also, simple tip: did you try to run this little script alone (changing `#someButton` of course) ? It may be enough for you :)

Comment: Your comments are helping me to make progress :-) using $('#someButton').removeAttr('disabled') I was able to make the button enabled, but now, after it is clicked I am getting a comment that the username/password are not correct, which is not true because when I insert them manually, it works. I think it is because of the form class which remains incorrect. Now I am trying to change the class programatically.

Comment: I tried  `form.DomContainer.Eval(string.Format("$('#{0}').removeClass(\"old_class_name\").addClass(\"new_class_name\")", form.Name));`   and also  `form.DomContainer.Eval(string.Format("document.getElementsByName('{0}').className = \"new_class_name\"", form.Name));`  none worked!

Comment: It seems there's a lot of logic in the JavaScript related to this form, so it would be better for you to just make your page behave like an human, I mean everything you do when you fill the form manually should be also done when you fillin the form automatically, you should not copy/paste the JS code in your code (it may be too complicated, and what if this code change ? yours would be broken). Did you try this: `$('#someInputYouFilled').trigger('keyup');` (or `keydown` or `keypress` or `blur`). Also, you have to do the work in JS but in your browser first, and when it works try it with WatiN.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right mix of technical requirements then you want Single-Site-Sign-On (SSSO).

Not all of my clients have SSL and I don't want my user name and password on all of their sites. They are however all on the same server. Since my site supports SSL I can log in to my own site securely.

What you need to do conceptually speaking is log the IP of the administrator account along with the data/time stamp. Then if you visit your client's website (again, on the same server) from that same IP you can have your scripting language check the file. I require a short time-span (anywhere between 30 seconds to two minutes tops) and the same IP address. You can add additional technical requirements to strengthen security of course though your options will be limited as the domain name will be different. If the IP matches the criteria emulate the user being authenticated (static obviously since you likely won't/shouldn't have your administrative account information on their site) and you can be automatically signed in.

Comment: Does SSSO can really be applied using a 3rd party website ?

Comment: You have to implement the code that SETS on your admin domain and then you have to implement the code that GETS on the client's domain. Both should be reading a flat-file, I recommend `$domain.'^^'.$ip.'^^'.$time` in the flat-file, `explode` the '^^' characters (if using PHP) and assign the variables. It should take an experienced programmer about an hour to two hours, longer for less experienced though it reduces the chances of signing in on a non-SSL site and thus helps strengthen your security if implemented and **used** correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it: so you have to modify the 3rd party website ? This is indeed not possible.

Comment: If you can not modify the code then SSSO won't work. The best you can do is have your user/pass saved and filled in via `autocomplete`. (Real) Opera (12.1/12.5 Alpha and earlier) has a Login button that will fill in `autocomplete` data automatically even if the website explicitly disables `autocomplete`. So long as it's third party that is the best you can do unless you're going to make a browser extension yourself.