# Accessing data from external websites to 'create' own application of that data

Tags: php, database, laravel

Wow, i hope i have written the title in a correct way, because i really have no idea how this is called.

Let me explain what i am looking for.

I have a simple application. And it contains the following:
- Frontpage (salespage)
- Admin area
- Member area
- Database to provide the app of data

I have hosted the basics of this application on a server, let's call it 'www.the.app'. And i have written it in PHP using Laravel.

Now i want to use the functions of the app, which is hosted on www.the.app and use the functions like the admin area, member area, the frontpage and create my own database on 'www.awesome.app'.

What would be the best way to make such a thing happen?
I am not looking for direct solutions. I am just looking for information to point me in the right direction to be able to make the above reality. Anything would be apreciated, like information, a name i can search on, what ever is related to this.

And if there is any more information needed, let me know please :)

Comment: `CURL` is a good approach to do it.Also you will be needing `PHP DOM` too for extracting data from the other site to show on your own site..!

Comment: Is both pages your own? Why not just copy the code?

Comment: @Andreas No it is not both pages i own. I own the 'www.the.app' where the application basics are stored and people who want to use the app, want to use the app on their own custom domain, let's say 'www.awesome.app'. They don't need to store the data of the app locally or on their server. They just use their own database, using the pre-defined options i set on www.the.app

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai, can you maybe tell me a bit more about this? Because i will probably not have access to the domain of the client.

Comment: @Jeroen : What you are trying to do is called Data Scrapping.It's like extracting data from other sites to which you don't have access really..! :D

Comment: you cant use the functions from another site, as you ask, only the data

Comment: Yup..My Mistake you can't use the functions but you can get the data only from the site just as @Dagon said..!

Comment: Okay thank you all for that information. So my best option would be to 'install' the app on the clients server? 

I wish i had some sort of example which could explain what i'm looking for. I will keep searching for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is exactly how you can do it :

### 1) To Auto Login To The Site :

**Note :** As you will need to probably get data from login based site so you can auto login to the site through using `CURL` while using User Credentials with it.

**To Learn How To Login Through CURL.Take A Look At :**

> [Using PHP & Curl to login to my websites form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049393/using-php-curl-to-login-to-my-websites-form)

### 2) Extracting Data After Logging In Through CURL :

**Note :** After logging to the site now you will need to use `PHP DOM` to extract data from the site.So you can extract data something like this way by using `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` Library.

**PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser :**

LINK : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

**Sample Code For Downloading All Images From A Link :**

**Note :** Following code will download all the images present at the URL given in the code.

```
<?php
// Make sure to include the library php file
include('simple_html_dom.php');

//URL To Download Images From
$url = "http://www.facebook.com/"

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html($url);

// Find all images 
$i=1;
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) { 
$url = $element->src;
$img = "/my_folder/image_".$i.".png";
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: @Jeroen : It if solved your question.Please make sure to you mark it as accepted answer so that the question can be considered solved..!

Comment: It helped me for sure yes! But it hasn't solved my question quite yet. I keep searching for an example so you know what i am talking about

Comment: @Jeroen : I don't know what you may be looking for but I showed you exactly how you can do it.And I am not gettting what you are really looking for???