# Keeping session alive with Curl and PHP

Tags: php, session, curl

I'm trying to connect to an API, authenticate a user and then view the user details. This is accomplished by first accessing the login endpoint at

```
http://api.example.com/login/<username>/<password>
```

to log in and then the following to view user details:

```
http://api.example.com/user/
```

This all works in a web browser. However, once I try to use Curl, the login works fine, but when attempting to view user details, I get back a 401, unauthorized error. I believe this is because Curl isn't saving the session cookies properly? Can someone point out why it isn't working and how to fix it? I've tried searching stack exchange, however, none of the solutions I've tried have worked for my situation. The code I'm using to curl the endpoints is shown below. Thanks!

```
define("COOKIE_FILE", "cookie.txt");

// Login the user
$ch = curl_init('http://api.example.com/login/joe/smith');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
echo curl_exec ($ch);

// Read the session saved in the cookie file
echo "<br/><br/>";
$file = fopen("cookie.txt", 'r');
echo fread($file, 100000000);   
echo "<br/><br/>";

// Get the users details
$ch = curl_init('http://api.example.com/user');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
echo curl_exec ($ch);
```

This code will output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 22 Oct 2012 21:23:57 GMT Server: LiteSpeed Connection: close X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.14 Set-Cookie: cfapi=f481129c9616b8f69cc36afe16466545; path=/ Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json X-Powered-By: CFWAPI 0.1a Content-Length: 46 {"status":200,"msg":"Successfully Logged In."}

# Netscape HTTP Cookie File # http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html # This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk. api.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   0   cfapi 94f63b07ccf7e34358c1c922341c020f 

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Date: Mon, 22 Oct 2012 21:23:57 GMT Server: LiteSpeed Connection: close X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.14 Set-Cookie: cfapi=a8eb015a7c423dde95aa01579c4729a4; path=/ Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json X-Powered-By: CFWAPI 0.1a Content-Length: 49 {"status":401, "msg":"You need to login first!"}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You also need to set the option `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`.

The manual describes this as

> The name of the file containing the cookie data. The cookie file can
>   be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a
>   file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies are loaded, but
>   cookie handling is still enabled.

Since you are using the cookie jar you end up saving the cookies when the requests finish, but since the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` is not given, cURL isn't sending any of the saved cookies on subsequent requests.

Comment: Doh! Can't believe I missed that option, it makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: is it possible to set the cookie as a variable (i do not want to pass a file each time)?

Comment: @trainoasis See option `CURLOPT_COOKIE`

Comment: But, if i need to save session then?

Answer (score 33):

You have correctly used "CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR" (writing) but you also need to set "CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE" (reading)

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
```

Answer (score 26):

This is how you do CURL with sessions

```
//initial request with login data

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

//another request preserving the session

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/profile');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
```

I've seen this on ImpressPages

Comment: Here you are not creating a new connection. You are using the same connection.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me

Answer (score 20):

Yup, often called a 'cookie jar'  Google should provide many examples:

http://devzone.zend.com/16/php-101-part-10-a-session-in-the-cookie-jar/

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/cookiejar.html <- good example IMHO

Copying that last one here so it does not go away...

> Login to on one page and then get another page passing all cookies from the first page along Written by Mitchell

```
<?php
/*
This script is an example of using curl in php to log into on one page and 
then get another page passing all cookies from the first page along with you.
If this script was a bit more advanced it might trick the server into 
thinking its netscape and even pass a fake referer, yo look like it surfed 
from a local page.
*/

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.myterminal.com/checkpwd.asp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "UserID=username&password=passwd");

ob_start();      // prevent any output
curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command
ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output

curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.myterminal.com/list.asp");

$buf2 = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo "<PRE>".htmlentities($buf2);
?>
```

Comment: I was having issues with the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE. I thought I had to always use both. As soon as I followed your code, what I was trying to do worked! Thanks!