# Session variables are being overwritten when i reload the page after login using facebook oauth in codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, oauth

I am using facebook oAuth in my website which is developed using CodeIgniter. When a user login using Facebook oAuth I am setting a variable to check in the future whether the user is logged in or not. That session variable is available till i redirect to some other page or reload the page. After that It is not available. It is being overwritten

**Why is my session variable's are destroying after the next request?**

Comment: is the Facebook oAuth using cURL?

Comment: Yea It is. I am creating it using the following link. http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2012/04/using-facebook-php-sdk-3-with-codeigniter-2-1/

Comment: take a look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020404/keeping-session-alive-with-curl-and-php