# Keep php curl alive for subsequent new requests

Tags: php, php-curl

I have already posted this question in stack programmers and haven't received any solution till date. So I am re-posting here

I am trying to scrape a site using php curl. Initially captcha has to be provided along with username and password for authentication. After logging in, to view one of the page link again new captcha has to be provided. I am able to successfully log in using first captcha. The problem arises when I grab the inside page captcha and return as response, the existing curl connection gets terminated and I have to start again by logging in. The site uses session cookie. Is there any possible method to maintain the session by using curl or fsockopen or anything?

Comment: Save the cookie in a jar and then use that jar for the new curl instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping session alive with Curl and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020404/keeping-session-alive-with-curl-and-php)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: I tried that.. Usually it works 90% of cases. May be I am missing something.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks. Shall check it.