# How to scrape a website that uses session login using php

Tags: php, session, curl, cookies

i have been trying to scrape a website which requires login. Login in POST Request, I have done it successfully. But the links after logged in doesn't gets scraped. It Says " Session Expired" when scraped in curl PHP. I don't know what happens there. Please let me know and solve the problem if possible.

I had scraped many websites but this is little bit different in strategy.

url:http://www.example.com/login   --> Required post request with username and password as parameters. Now the problem comes!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try reading this too! [GitHub Link](https://gist.github.com/anchetaWern/6150297)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should accept the session cookie, store it, and resend it on the next request.

[Keeping session alive with Curl and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020404/keeping-session-alive-with-curl-and-php)

Comment: Thanks Viktor!! It Worked !