# How to maintain session with curl php?

Tags: php, session, curl

I know that this question have been asked many times before in Stack-overflow but none of the answers solved my problem.

I am writing a php script that uses curl to remotely browse JSP site:
here is my code:

```
<?php
$loginUrl = 'http://ccc.hyundai-motor.com/servlet/ccc.login.CccLoginServlet';

 $sh = curl_share_init();
curl_share_setopt($sh, CURLSHOPT_SHARE, CURL_LOCK_DATA_COOKIE);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SHARE, $sh);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'the post data including my username and password and other hidden fields');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($ch);

$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SHARE, $sh);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL,'http://ccc.hyundai-motor.com/servlet/ccc/admin/user/UserInfoServlet?cmd=myUserInfo');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch2);  
print $result;
curl_share_close($sh);
curl_close($ch);
curl_close($ch2);
?>
```

When I execute the code the cookie file is created but i get an error "session lost, please re-login".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020404/keeping-session-alive-with-curl-and-php#13020494

Comment: I have already read that question before but nothing new, can you be more specific about the problem of my code?

Comment: Thing you should you only one of these `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR|CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`  `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` in the first call and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` in the second part  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13020460/4916265

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a handle via [`curl_share_init`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-share-init.php) and pass it to each cURL instance otherwise the instances exist separately and cannot share the required session cookie.

An example from the PHP manual:

```
// Create cURL share handle and set it to share cookie data
$sh = curl_share_init();
curl_share_setopt($sh, CURLSHOPT_SHARE, CURL_LOCK_DATA_COOKIE);

// Initialize the first cURL handle and assign the share handle to it
$ch1 = curl_init("http://example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SHARE, $sh);

// Execute the first cURL handle
curl_exec($ch1);

// Initialize the second cURL handle and assign the share handle to it
$ch2 = curl_init("http://php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SHARE, $sh);

// Execute the second cURL handle
//  all cookies from $ch1 handle are shared with $ch2 handle
curl_exec($ch2);

// Close the cURL share handle
curl_share_close($sh);

// Close the cURL handles
curl_close($ch1);
curl_close($ch2);
```

Comment: I have tried as you said but it still giving the same error, i have updated the code in the question accordingly, please take a look.