# curl login to website and then navigate trough different links while logged in

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl to login to a website:

```
$credentials = [
    'user' => 'username',
    'password' => 'passowrd',
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://shop.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($credentials));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

It works to log in but once i'm logged in i need to go trough a few urls and crawl some data(which is available only after log in):

```
$products = ['1', '2', '3'];
foreach ($products as $id) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://shop.com/product.php?id=' . $id);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //do something with that response

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Is there a way to maintain that `session` started in the first `curl` request so i can use it in the `foreach` loop - so i can crawl my data?

Thank you!

Comment: [CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020404/keeping-session-alive-with-curl-and-php) ?

Comment: You could use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) and pass `['cookies' => true]` to your `Client` constructor. It will automatically maintain session/cookies and is generally much easier to use than curl.

Answer (score 0):

in your first request, you should save the cookie in a variable and use it in other requests. like this :

```
$credentials = [
    'user' => 'username',
    'password' => 'passowrd',
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://shop.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($credentials));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

get cookie and save in in `$cookie` variable :

```
prog_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi',$response,$m);
parse_str($m[1],$cookie);
```

and in other request you can use it like this:

```
$products = ['1', '2', '3'];
foreach ($products as $id) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://shop.com/product.php?id=' . $id);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID='.$cookie['PHPSESSID']);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //do something with that response

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Hey @MohammadRajabloo, can you please tell me why do i have to set CURLOPT_HEADER? I've read the documentation but i don't get it :(

Comment: @emma. because we need to get the cookie from response header. set-cookie row contains cookie.