# Login to vbulletin via curl

Tags: php, curl, vbulletin

I am currently trying to figure out how to log into vbulletin from a remote server, the get information from an array of pages that require you to be logged in.

I have found many resources but nothing I seem to find has gotten me any closer. The version of vbulletin is 4.2.2 and I can't seem to log in. I'm new to curl and really have no idea where to start.

The purpose of this is to parse through members profiles and see who has been inactive for x amount of time. So I'm coming here to ask for help to find the right direction of getting this done.

Comment: I believe vbulletin has protection against CSRF. This would be kind of lengthy if you tried it with `php` and `curl`. You might want to dive into `python mechanize`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Login to site with curl in vBulletin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078426/login-to-site-with-curl-in-vbulletin)