# PHP - cURL post to website -> emulate browser (to do javascript) -> return html result

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I was wondering if it is possible (well anything is possible) to use cURL post to website (simulate a login) then to emulate browser (to allow javascript to process the login) then return html result after said script has run?

Here is a process tree.

cUrl -> login.php
           -> emulate browser to run javascript -> return html

Comment: I recommend to you http://phantomjs.org/index.html

Comment: Before phantomjs i used V8 php extension but its more difficult than phantom

Comment: It's duplicate post:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008817](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008817/login-to-remote-site-with-php-curl)

Comment: Hows it a duplicate, im asking about the javascript portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phantomjs.org/index.html did what I needed to do, thanks for the suggestions :)