# PHP: Log in to a .aspx site and retrieve response

Tags: php, asp.net, webforms

How can I log in to a website's .aspx page and retrieve the response? I would like to log in to www.laterooms.com/hoteliers. I've found many examples for logging in to standard POST forms but not for this kind of form.

Is it also possible to maintain a cookie container in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna use cURL for that, it's a library that allows you to communicate over many different protocols (http, https, ftp, telnet, etc.) You can do a login by using the library and keep a session in PHP. Here's an example that might get you on track: [Login to remote site with PHP cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008817/login-to-remote-site-with-php-curl)