# Using curl with email and password

Tags: php, api, laravel, curl

I have an api to export some information to a `csv` file. The API is correct and it is downloading my file when I access it from the browser. I need to access this API from the terminal and download the file without having to go to the browser.

My route for the API looks like this:

```
Route::get('/api/file/export', 'File\FileController@export', [
    'middleware'=>'auth.basic'
]);
```

I tried using curl like this:

```
curl --user email:password http://example.com/api/file/export
```

I have tried different curl commands but each of then displays the redirect to login html. When I use `-O` the command for downloading a file, it downloads a file that has the redirect to login link.

```
curl --user email:password -O http://example.com/api/file/export
```

Am I calling the API correctly? How else can I access the API from the terminal?

Comment: It looks like your using basic HTTP authentication, but what you describe as the error seems like a typical username/password auth. Have you modified the `auth.basic` middleware from what is default in Laravel?

Comment: No I have not modified the `auth.basic` file. What changes should I make?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I'm mistaken but you shouldn't see "login html" if you are using HTTP auth. It should just be a 401 Unauthorized response, thats it. Regardless, usually you would use token-based authentication when you are building an API that needs security. [Fortunately Laravel has that sort of thing baked in](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport) (although I know it requires you change gears).

Comment: I was getting 302 redirect as the HTTP response, but I actually decided to switch to token-based authentication yesterday. I am adding the API to an old project that uses Laravel 5.1 so I can't use Laravel Passport instead am using this [plugin](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel). Then I will use a Python script to call the API from the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You should first be logged in your website. You can try this:
`curl --user email:password http://domain.tld/login_page`

And then use the cookies for your second request:
`curl --cookie http://domain.tld/file/to/export`

If that is not working, you need to do the whole submit action with cURL, meaning doing POST request with email and password etc.

Someone gave a [good solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008817/login-to-remote-site-with-php-curl)

PS: Checkout if you don't need a token to request your API too.