# Get Content from a php web page with PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the content generated by a PHP page, but this PHP page is generated (by an external site, not mine) after https authentication.

When I try to get the content with `file_get_contents`, I receive an error message ("you are not logged in"), but I'm logged in, with another page of the same browser.

Comment: You'll need to show the code you have and explain the problem more clearly if you want to get any good answers.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed on the server, not on the client (your browser).
 To be able to get the contents with php you need to use curl.

Curl will allow you to log in, the exact process depends on the website you are trying to get, check this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008817/login-to-remote-site-with-php-curl)  about how to log in to a remote site with curl

Comment: OP is already using `file_get_contents` to get the contents though.