# PHP - Accept a steam trade offer with steam API

Tags: php, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I know that there is no method in the Steam API to accept a steam trade offer, but i know is possible to accept a trade offer making a post request by a url, but i don't know how to do it and i need some help.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you worked out so far and where do you need help?

Comment: i can get the trade offer i get, and i want to accept the active offers, just accept them like if i open the offer and click the accept button.

Comment: You said you know you htat you can accept an offer by sending a post request to an url. Figure out what data is transmitted. If you get all the data send it with cURL.

Comment: That's the problem, i don't know what data i need to send.

Comment: Check the requests with Developer Tools of your browser and the network tab

Comment: i need the request headers? or the cookies? i'm really lost on what i need and how to make the post giving the correct info.

Comment: I think the page requires authentication? Then you need to login to it first. Afterwards you can perform your request. This would be 2 cURL requests. Check the "Headers" section at the bottom should be "Query String Parameters" (Chrome). And check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008817/login-to-remote-site-with-php-curl

Comment: This NodeJS libary can help: https://github.com/Alex7Kom/node-steam-tradeoffers