# Download csv file from url and save on server with username password

Tags: php, csv

I want to download a csv file from a url and save that on my server.
But the URL requires a username/password.

And I also want to include a timeout, so that it will not try to download it longer than 30 seconds.

I currently tried this, but that is missing the username / password.

How can I achive this?

```
file_put_contents("file.csv", fopen("http://url.com/path/to/file.csv", 'r'));
```

Comment: You'll probably need to use cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login to remote site with PHP cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008817/login-to-remote-site-with-php-curl)

Answer (score 0):

You need download file with curl

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$url = "http://url/path/file.csv";
$fileout =  '/yourpath/filecurl.csv';
$fp = fopen ($fileout , 'w+');
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
// write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Then read the file in a normal way with the method you like, this is basically the idea

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but that does not seem to work. It does not download/save any file.

Comment: This found, change quotes at this `"$username:$password"`

Comment: Thanks, but I get multiple errors: `failed to open stream: Permission denied` and `curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource` and `fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Comment: You Tried first change permision dir fileout `$fileout =  '/yourpath/filecurl.csv';`  chmod 755? or 777, second change time CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, tried this!

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried setting the permissions right. I increased the time in CURLOPT_TIMEOUT but I still get the same error's. Do I first need to create the file `/yourpath/filecurl.csv` mannualy or will it be created by curl?

Comment: not `/yourpath/filecurl.csv` create automatic by script, but need permission 777 in this path `/yourpath`