# PHP cURL Login For Laravel

Tags: curl, laravel-5

I implemented the following code for automatic login and set session using cURL. It will not authenticate. Please explain to me how Laravel authentication using PHP cURL works.

```
$url = 'http://localhost/site/login'; (Laravel Login URl)

$username = 'xxx@xxx.com';  

$password = 'password'; 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I am getting the

> 419 Sorry, your session has expired

How do I pass Laravel CSRF token using cURL in same domain between core PHP and Laravel?

Comment: It depends on how you've got authentication set up, but HTTP Basic Authentication is *unusual* for a Laravel install. You'd typically do this with a form POST and storing the cookies for subsequent requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login to remote site with PHP cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008817/login-to-remote-site-with-php-curl)

Answer (score 3):

#### Laravel 5 with cURL :

> Use '_token'   => csrf_token() for laravel CSRF

Also you can disable the csrf validation on specific route to `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` class

```php
    protected $except = [
        'custom/login'
    ];
```

> Outside Laravel APP :

```php
    $attr = [
       'username' => $username,
       'password' => $pass
    ];
    $curl = curl_init();
    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://testcURL.com/custom/login',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'login',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $attr
    ]);
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: The File is out side of laravel application . How can i use the `csrf_token()` token in the CURL. Because  csrf_token() is Laravel helper function.

Comment: Also you can disable the csrf validation on laravel app specific route to app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php class

Comment: How can i  use with out  disabling csrf_token() and i want to retrieve laravel session out side of the application in same domain